# Why is the variable being replaced with an empty space?

Tags: azure, yaml, azure-pipelines-yaml

This is part of a wider set of yaml pipelines for a deployment, this bit concerns taking the function host key from the key vault, and then inserting it into the next stage as a variable, where its then used as part of the replacement when called by another file.

```
  - task: AzureCLI@2
    name: outputs
    displayName: Get Hostkey
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: ${{parameters.azureServiceConnection}}
      scriptType: bash
      scriptLocation: inlineScript
      addSpnToEnvironment: true
      inlineScript: |
        functionHostKey=$(sh pipelines/templates/getHostKey.sh ${{parameters.functionAppName}})
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=functionHostKey;isoutput=true]$functionHostKey"



  - task: PythonScript@0
    inputs:
      scriptSource: 'filePath'
      scriptPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/_search/scripts/deployment-script/deployBlob.py'
      inputVar: $[ dependencies.AzureCLI@2.outputs['functionHostKey'] ]
    env:
      custom_skill_uri: "https://${{parameters.functionAppName}}.azurewebsites.net/api/skill-customfields?code=${{variables.functionHostKey}}&clientId=default"
      functionHostKey: ${{variables.functionHostKey}}
      search_key: ${{parameters.cognitiveSearchKey}}
      search_endpoint: "https://${{parameters.cognitiveSearchName}}.search.windows.net"
      datasource_name: km3-datasource
      app_id : ${{parameters.appId}}
      app_secret : ${{parameters.appSecret}}
      tenant_id : ${{parameters.tenantId}}
      cog_multi_account_serv_key : ${{parameters.cognitiveAccountKey}}
      indexer_name : km3-indexer
      index_name : km3-index
      skillset_name : km3-skillset
      api_version : 2021-04-30-Preview
      search_service_name : ${{parameters.cognitiveSearchName}}
      pipeline_workspace : '$(Pipeline.Workspace)'
      storage_conString: ${{parameters.storageConnectionString}}
      container: ${{parameters.container}}
      folder: ${{parameters.folder}}
```

When I run the pipelines, the Get Hostkey task is running fine and is getting the host key following the template, and the replacement of the uri is working, as the the first parameter replaces with the correct function app name is inserted, but the variables replaces itself with nothing at all, therefore the output URI looks like:

```
https://funcappname.azurewebsites.net/api/skill-customfields?code=&clientId=default
```

If I switch to using macro syntax for my variable, then it returns:

```
https://funcappname.azurewebsites.net/api/skill-customfields?code=$(functionHostKey)&clientId=default
```

Any idea why this is happening? Am I just not taking in the environment variable from the stage before properly? Or is it not being properly assigned?

Comment: these two tasks are executed in different stages ? the synthax does not look correct: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#use-outputs-in-a-different-stage

Comment: @Thomas They're part of the same stage and job, they're just two separate tasks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a variable from a previous task in the same job, you don't need to set `isoutput=true` but in your case you probably want to set `issecret=true`

```yaml
- task: AzureCLI@2
  # name: outputs => don't need to specify a name
  displayName: Get Hostkey
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: ${{parameters.azureServiceConnection}}
    scriptType: bash
    scriptLocation: inlineScript
    addSpnToEnvironment: true
    inlineScript: |
      functionHostKey=$(sh pipelines/templates/getHostKey.sh ${{parameters.functionAppName}})
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=functionHostKey;]$functionHostKey"

- script: echo $(functionHostKey)
```